# Invalid login, please try again in moodle E-learning after installing boost learning theme

Tags: mamp, moodle, mariadb-10.4, moodle-theme

After had installed the boost learning theme in Moodle , i faced invalid login please try again

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question? It will be more helpful if you describe how you installed theme, which versions you are using  or what are log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of reasons, to work around it:

If you have access to the database, then you can try to reset the password using SQL:

```
UPDATE mdl_user
SET password = md5('yournewpassword')
WHERE username = 'yourusername'
```

Or if you have command line access, then you can use this:

```
php admin/cli/reset_password.php --help
```